# GNU Make Exits Due to Syntax Error in If Statement

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu

I'm building a C++ project using *GNU Make* (version *3.80*). The makefile is auto-generated from the tool I'm using (*IBM Rational Rhapsody*). An example of this makefile is at the end of this post.

This makefile has a mechanism that allows me to specify a directory for object files (the `OBJ_DIR` variable). If this is set, the variable `CREATE_OBJ_DIR` is set up with the command `if not exist $(OBJ_DIR) mkdir $(OBJ_DIR)`. This is then called for each object file in the project.

Running this makefile *without* setting an object file directory works as expected; the code is compiled without issues. But running it with `OBJ_DIR` set to 'build' causes the following error:

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\make52963.sh: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\make52963.sh: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
C:\Tools\XXX\x86-win32\bin\make.exe: *** [build/Example.o] Error 2
```

I'm certain the issue is within the rule for '/build/Example.o', when `$(CREATE_OBJ_DIR)` is called. If I manually edit the rule and replace `$(CREATE_OBJ_DIR)` with `mkdir $(OBJ_DIR)`, the command is executed correctly. If I then replace it with `if not exist build mkdir build` directly, to eliminate any issues due to variable expansion, the same error appears.

Other things I have tried:

1. Run a `cmd` shell with the same environment variables set as when the makefile is called, and attempted to run the `if not exist build mkdir build` command. No issues with this.
2. Ensure that no trailing characters are present in the command run within the makefile. None appear to be present.

My only conclusion at this point is that something about *if* statements causes the makefile to fail, but I'm not sure what. Is there anything else I should try to track down the source of this problem? Am I missing something obvious.

Let me know if more details are required.

*Note: I've edited this makefile pretty heavily, so it's just to give an idea of what I'm using, and probably won't execute. Some of the environment variables below are set up in a batch file prior to calling `make`, but I'm confident they're not part of the issue I'm seeing, as the makefile works correctly except in the situation described above.*

```
CPU = XXX
TOOL = gnu

INCLUDE_QUALIFIER=-I
LIB_CMD=$(AR)
LINK_CMD=$(LD)

CPP_EXT=.cpp
H_EXT=.h
OBJ_EXT=.o
EXE_EXT=.out
LIB_EXT=.a

TARGET_NAME=Example

all : $(TARGET_NAME)$(EXE_EXT) Example.mak

TARGET_MAIN=Example

LIBS=
INCLUDE_PATH=
ADDITIONAL_OBJS=

OBJS= \
  build/Example.o \

OBJ_DIR=build

ifeq ($(OBJ_DIR),)
CREATE_OBJ_DIR=
else
CREATE_OBJ_DIR= if not exist $(OBJ_DIR) mkdir $(OBJ_DIR)
endif

build/Example.o : src/Example.cpp 
    @echo Compiling src/Example.cpp
    $(CREATE_OBJ_DIR)
    @$(CXX) $(C++FLAGS) -o build/Example.o src/Example.cpp
```

Comment: just a quick question: are you indenting with tab ?

Comment: @MortenJensen Yes, the build rule is indented with tabs.

Comment: Your text is very long, but there's no trace of the offending `make52963.sh` anywhere. Find out how this is created and what it contains...

Comment: I suspect your version of GNU make (3.8 is not a valid GNU make release number; maybe you're using 3.80?) is invoking a POSIX shell, not command.com.  If that's true then the statement `if not exist $(OBJ_DIR) mkdir $(OBJ_DIR)` is not valid.

Comment: @FelixPalmen That's a fair point. This must be generated everytime I run `make` but it has a different number each time. I can't see it in my Temp folder (it doesn't even appear temporarily during the build process). Not sure how else to find this.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes, it is 3.80. Not sure if this a good test, but I tried putting `dir` into the build rule, assuming that it wouldn't run for a POSIX shell. It printed out a directory listing, so that surely means it's a cmd shell?

Comment: Nope.  `dir` works on GNU/Linux so some POSIX environments provide it.  Try something like `rem this is a comment` and see what happens.  I suppose it's even possible that whatever environment you have does something magical with it.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provided the error output you get from your sample makefile at the end of your question.  Does that complain about `local\Temp\make52963.sh` or similar as well?  You might try a newer/different version of GNU make.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking to complex. A far simpler solution here is to use:

```
mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
```

This will also make it work if `OBJ_DIR=my/little/obj/dir/deep/down/the/rabit/hole`.

Comment: That's definitely a good solution, the issue is that this is an auto-generated makefile. I don't think there's a parameter that allows me to change that. I'm more interested in why the original command isn't working when the syntax is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following Makefile:

```
OBJ_DIR=foo

CREATE_OBJ_DIR= if not exist $(OBJ_DIR) mkdir $(OBJ_DIR)

$(info CREATE_OBJ_DIR=$(CREATE_OBJ_DIR))

all:
        $(CREATE_OBJ_DIR)
```

and it's output:

```
% make         
CREATE_OBJ_DIR=if not exist foo mkdir foo
if not exist foo mkdir foo
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Your "if" statement is simply not valid **shell** syntax. On the other hand if OBJ_DIR is empty then CREATE_OBJ_DIR is empty and that is valid.